# How to create sub-dataframes setting 3 variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with 6 variables (x, y, E, freq, Perc, Rip).

```
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

a<-c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
b<-c(15,25,35,45,55,65,75,85,95,105)
x<-rep(a,3)
y<-rep(b,3)
E<-sample(30)
freq<-as.character(rep(c(100,200,300),10))

Perc_Points<- percent(seq(0.9,0.1,by=-0.1))

data<-data.frame(x,y,freq,E)

data1<-group_by(data,freq)

N <- 10
df <- vector("list", N)

df <- lapply(1:N, function(i)
                {  lista <- sapply(seq(0.9, 0.1, -0.1), 
                   function(pct) {sample_frac(data1, pct)}, 
                   simplify=FALSE)
                   names(lista) <- Perc_Points
                   xxxx <- bind_rows(lista, .id = "Perc")
                   df[[i]] <- xxxx
                })

df<-bind_rows(df, .id="Rip")
df<-data.frame(df)
```

Now i want to work with sub-dataframes of `df`, one for each different value of freq, Perc and Rip.

For example, a dataframe with `freq`= 100, `Perc`= 90%, `Rip`=1, another with `freq`= 100, `Perc`= 90%, `Rip`=2, etc...

I try with `group_by(df, Perc, freq, Rip)`, but there is a problem: i have to apply `krige` function to each of this sub-dataframe, and this function doesn't work with grouped_df. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `split`

```
lst <- split(df, list(df$Rip, df$Perc, df$freq), drop=TRUE)
```

and then loop over the `list` elements with `lapply` and apply the function

Or if we need to work with `dplyr`, use `do`

```
df %>%
  group_by(Rip, Perc, freq) %>%
  do(data.frame(krigeFunc(arg1, arg2,..))) #not clear about the function
```

Comment: can you show me how to loop the list element? the function that i have to apply is:
`nearest = krige(E ~ 1, df, grid, nmax = 1)`, 
where df is, each time, the singol sub-dataframe, and grid is this:

`x.range <- range(df$x)  
y.range <- range(df$y)
grid <- expand.grid(x = seq(from = x.range[1], to = x.range[2], by = 1), y = seq(from = y.range[1], to = y.range[2], by = 1))
coordinates(grid) <- ~x + y
gridded(grid) <- TRUE`